# QPSK constellation Zero Crossings

Tags: digital-communications

What causes zero crossings in a QPSK constellation to be a a problem for linearity or PAPR ( Peak to Average Power Ratio)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23605/235) for a brief description of why $\pi/4$-QPSK generally is preferred over plain QPSK in satellite channels.

Comment: how is the constellation for $\pi/4$-QPSK different from plain QPSK?

Comment: 135 degrees phase shift for pi/4 QPSK  vs 180 degrees for plain QPSK and 90 degrees for OQPSK